# Is there a way in Total.js to add to @{head} from a view?

Tags: total.js

I'm using total.js and wanting to add a page-specific CSS link tag to a page's HTML `<head>` from within a view, rather than coding it into the route's controller.

I've tried to use `@(head(css('page.css'))}` but that results in a server error.  Using `@{css('page.css')}` prints out the CSS link tag as part of the `@{body}`.  Yet, the `@{meta('Page Title')}` directive is able to direct its output to the `<head>` section of the page.

Am I missing something or is it just not possible in this version of total.js?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@{head('/css/page.css')}`.